# Notification bar and adding a browser out-dated script

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am currently working on a notification bar http://jsfiddle.net/nZe8t/ and I would like to add a browser out-date message script which detects if the used browser is up to date.

The action to show the bar is currently applied to a button, but I want the notification bar to appear when it detects an out-dated browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using jQuery you can use jQuery.browser to detect what type and which version of browser the user is viewing the site with. If you add a check into your domready event, you can detect the version there and show the warning message if needed.

Hiding the message when clicking any link is as simple as adding an onclick event to the body on all A elements and hiding the warning message if it is being shown when the event is fired.

```
jQuery("body a").click(function(){/*hide messages*/})
```

jQuery.browser: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Example:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version=="6.0") {
    //show the warning box, the user is using IE6!
}
```

Comment: @ Seidr I added the closing function as follow: $('.message').click(function(){              
$(this).animate({top: -$(this).outerHeight()}, 500);.        });                  
});

Comment: ..and what was your result? You need to be a bit clearer with asking questions and responding to answers to make it easier for people to help you without having to guess exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @ Seidr Great! But how can I have the bar appear when it detects that the browser is outdated? The bar is currently triggered with a button.

Comment: You must define "outdated" yourself. What do YOU considere to be outdated? The page I linked shows typical output for jQuery.browser and jQuery.browser.version, so you can state yourself which versions you consider to be outdated (for example, IE7, Firefox 1.7.12).

Comment: I agree. Maybe outdated is the wrong term here. I want to remind users that they are not using the latest browser version.

Comment: If you knew the most recent version of the browser (that jQuery can detect), then that would be possible..however I wouldn't recommend displaying that warning if the user just does not have the most recent version. Perhaps on older versions that are known to have multiple issues with layout etc (IE6 IE7 as examples), but users sometimes stick with older (stable) versions, with no detrimental effect to how websites appear to them. Just a thought :)

Comment: This jQuery plugin may be of interest to you - it appears to be a pretty solid method of detecting precisely which browser the user has, and performing actions based upon that information. It could prove to be helpful as a reference: http://jreject.turnwheel.com/

Comment: Indeed, I agree with your argument. It can have a counter effect. I will just use the jQuery.browser in the footer. Tnx!